# Does location of `e.preventDefault()` matter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use `preventDefault()` in my jquery functions to prevent submit buttons from submitting the normal way. Does the location of `preventDefault()` matter. Does it have to come first or can be last thing in the function?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, it doesn't matter:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

This is different from returning `false`, since when you returns, everything else in the function are abandoned.

As said in the MDC link given above:

> Calling `preventDefault` during any
>   stage of event flow cancels the event,
>   meaning that any default action
>   normally taken by the implementation
>   as a result of the event will not
>   occur.

Comment: li, looks like you are right, i have return false in mind , thanks for clarifying that, i removed my answer

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't matter, but I like to put it first. The intended behavior is clear on a quick scan of the code when it's right up top.

Answer (score 1):

## December 2023 update:

It depends on the nature of the default action implemented by browser vendors. It some cases a failure of preventing the default action from firing may complicate debugging and/or make user UI poorer.

---

For example, special caution should be taken when using [`preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) in conjunction with the form's [`submit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubmitEvent) event.

Imagine that we want to submit a form using [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) instead of letting the browser to take a user to a new URL (the default action).

When `preventDefault()` **comes last**, as in the following example, and our custom logic throws an exception, the browser will print an error message in the console and *immediately* redirects a user to the URL specified in the form's action. This leads to a hard-to-debug error, since you will not notice an error (unless `Preserve log` browser setting is enabled) and the server response will be printed as is by the browser (JSON, for example):

```
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
    someRequestThatCanThrowAnException.make();
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Whereas in the example below `preventDefault()` **comes first** so we prevent the default action from happening no matter whether our custom logic fails or not:

```
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    someRequestThatCanThrowAnException.make();
    throw new Error('another error');
});
```

---

Therefore, it might be a **good practice** to always put `preventDefault()` as close to the beginning of the callback function as possible by default, in order to avoid spending hours on debugging when placed at the end.

Answer (score 0):

It only matters if somewhere in the code ran from your handler something checks whether the event has been canceled or not:

```js
addEventListener("something", (evt) => {
  doSomethingWithEvent(evt, "before");
  evt.preventDefault();
  doSomethingWithEvent(evt, "after");
});

function doSomethingWithEvent(evt, pos) {
  if (!evt.defaultPrevented) {
    console.log("I do something", pos);
  }
  else {
    console.log("I do not do something", pos);
  }
}

dispatchEvent(new Event("something", { cancelable: true }));
```

If you're sure nothing from your handler will check the `defaultPrevented` property, then it's the same, even if some other code checks it outside of the handler.