# jquery simple collapsible list issue

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a simple collapsible multi-level where each ul is collapsible. I am having a hard time figuring what I am doing wrong.
my script is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vTdRg/)

```
<ul id="usernav">
<li>Manage
    <ul >
        <li >child11
         <ul>
             <li> some1</li>
             <li> some2</li>
         </ul>
        </li>
        <li>child12</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>Subscriptions
    <ul>
        <li>E-Briefings</li>
        <li>E-Briefings Subscriptions</li>
        <li>Knowledge Briefings</li>
    </ul>
</li>
  <li>Media Store
    <ul>
        <li>Image Store</li>
        <li>Document Store</li>
        <li>Media Store</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

My script is

```
 $('#usernav').find('ul').hide();    
$('li').click(function() {
    $(this).children('ul').toggle();
});
```

Comment: when you are clicking a nested li, that click also bubbles to the parent li, you need to prevent bubbling http://jsfiddle.net/vTdRg/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click the child of an element, you're also clicking the element. So when you click a child `li`, the event also fires on the parent `li`s. Use `stopPropagation()` to prevent the event from bubbling.

http://jsfiddle.net/nrVYn/

```
$('#usernav').find('ul').hide();

$('li').click(function(e) {
    $(this).children('ul').toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: upvoted as it is the correct answer, but any application of either `e.stopPropagation()` or `e.preventDefault()` should always come first in order of operations.

Comment: @PlantTheIdea totally not true, it can appear anywhere in the handler

Comment: @PlantTheIdea please eleborate what you mean.

Comment: @PlantTheIdea "should" - Is this a personal preference or is there a technical reason?

Comment: my bad, i was operating on an old best practice, but turns out i was incorrect => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4476973/does-location-of-e-preventdefault-matter. disregard :)

Comment: @PlantTheIdea I suppose as a coding practice, it does make it harder to miss when it's the first statement.