# simplest jquery test doesn't work

Tags: jquery, testing

for some reason I just want to check if my jQuery loaded, but it doesn't work even though the src file in the script is a good link, any ideas?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="http://jquery.com/">jQuery</a>
    <script src="C:\wamp\www\jquery-test\jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $( "a" ).click(function( event ) {
            alert( "The link will no longer take you to jquery.com" );
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're not changing the target of the `a` tag.

Comment: even when i do only this: ` $(document).ready(function() {
   alert( "The link will no longer take you to jquery.com" );
  }); ` it's not working

Comment: check your console. You might get some errors there.

Comment: May be you are clicking before document is ready? Remove ready handler and check if it is working.

Comment: It does work: http://jsfiddle.net/ykurmangaliyev/4eu8n0r4/. Something's wrong with your jQuery import - check network log, is this file correctly loaded? Aren't there any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load Jquery from CDN should work for you , Please check updated code :

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="http://jquery.com/">jQuery</a>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script>

        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $( "a" ).click(function( event ) {
                alert( "The link will no longer take you to jquery.com" );
                event.preventDefault();
            });
        });

        </script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Your all other code seems fine , I just changed path to retrieve Jquery **jquery-1.11.3.min.js** and it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Load your jQuery from CDN instead of local path on your computer. This way, you dont need webserver running.

`https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js` instead of `C:\wamp\www\jquery-test\jquery-1.11.3.min.js`

Comment: It should be a comment, I guess.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev I think this is a valid answer, it will make that code working :)

Comment: That's why I have written "I guess" :) This will make the OP's code work, but it is not what he wants. Probably, he wants to load a file from a local file system.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code, since you are using wamp I have you can access jQuery on your local environment using this URL http://localhost/jquery-test/jquery-1.11.3.min.js

```
  <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="http://jquery.com/">jQuery</a>
        <script src="http://localhost/jquery-test/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script>

        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $( "a" ).click(function( event ) {
                alert( "The link will no longer take you to jquery.com" );
                event.preventDefault();
            });
        });

        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

If above code does not work then load jQuery from some CDN like this

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Changed jQuery include URL

Answer (score 0):

try this it will work, you need to put event.preventDefault(); in the begining.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "a" ).click(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
        alert( "The link will no longer take you to jquery.com" );
    });
});
```

Comment: It does not matter. It does work here: http://jsfiddle.net/ykurmangaliyev/4eu8n0r4/

Comment: it does matter i think

Comment: No, it doesn't :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4476973/does-location-of-e-preventdefault-matter

Answer (score 0):

```js
$( "a" ).click(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  alert( "The link will no longer take you to jquery.com" )  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://jquery.com/">jQuery</a>
```