# How to prevent nav from jumping back to top of page

Tags: jquery

Where do I insert `event.preventDefault()` in the code? When I push #toggle at the bottom of the page it takes me back to the top

```
$("#toggle").click(function(){
  if ( $("ul.nav > li").css("display") == "none")  {
    $("ul.nav > li").css("display", "block");
    $(".nav").css("background-color", "#F8C471");
    $("#toggle").css("color", "#fff");
    $(".nav").css("position", "sticky");
  } else {
    $("ul.nav > li").css("display", "none");
    $("#toggle").css("color", "#1B2631");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`event.preventDefault()` won't work in this case. As its name implies it will only prevent default functionality / behaviour of an event. You have to debug what function **#toggle** uses that causes the page to scroll to the top. Replace that function or detach it from that element.

Edit: If the **#toggle** is an `<a>` as commented by Phil, you can place the `event.preventDefault()` anywhere as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4476973/does-location-of-e-preventdefault-matter).

Comment: I imagine it's `<a id="toggle" href="#">Toggle</a>` or something similar

Comment: Yes makes sense if its an `<a>`. Hope Jacob can confirm this.