# For loop running only once while validating form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form and I am doing some form validation using JavaScript.

```js
function validate() {
    let arr = [];
    arr[0] = form.name ;
    arr[1] = form.mobNumber ;
    arr[2] = form.email ;
    arr[3] = form.query ;
    for (let num = 0; num < arr.length; num++){
        if (arr[num].value == ""){
        arr[num].placeholder = "This field is mandatory";
        arr[num].style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1)";
        arr[num].classList.add('redPlaceholder');
        return false;
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.redPlaceholder::placeholder {
    color: red;
    font-style: italic;
    font-family: 'Roboto' sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<form name="form" method="post" netlify id="form"  onsubmit="return validate()" >
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name"><br>
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail"><br>
<input type="number" name="mobNunber" placeholder="Contact Number"><br>
<textarea name="query" placeholder="Your Query" rows="5"></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

In the js part, I have an empty array and later add input fields of the form by accessing them through their name.
In the for loop I am checking if each of the input field is filled or not. If not, then I have some code to execute.That code block is running perfectly.

The problem is that when I click submit button with all fields empty, the code in the for loop runs only once - for the first input field. I think that there is some problem with the loop though I have checked the syntax several times.

Comment: There's a `return` statement in the `if` block, which makes the function terminate immediately.

Comment: @JohnGordon I am using return statement so that the form is not submitted (as per my knowledge).

Comment: I understand that.  You should wait to return false until after you have checked _all_ the values.  As it is, you're returning false on the _first_ blank value.

Comment: Add `var pass=true` before the `for` loop, and set if to `false` inside the `if` statement.  And remove the `return` from withing the loop.  After the loop, if `!pass` then `return false;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the html, you gave the mobilenumber input the name of `mobNunber` but the javascript looks for `mobNumber` so I fixed that. Simply checking if `arr.length == num` to return false during one of these incompleted inputs did not work so I made a variable that is ticked if one of the inputs was not filled in to return false after the for loop ends. I also added `arr[num].style.backgroundColor = "transparent";` so if the user fails to fill in an input, the background won't always stay as that purple-ish color even after filling out the input.

```js
function validate() {

    let err = false;
    let arr = [];
    arr[0] = form.name ;
    arr[1] = form.mobNumber ;
    arr[2] = form.email ;
    arr[3] = form.query ;
    for (let num = 0; num < arr.length; num++){
        if (arr[num].value == ""){
        arr[num].placeholder = "This field is mandatory";
        arr[num].style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1)";
        arr[num].classList.add('redPlaceholder');
                err = true;

        }
        else{
         arr[num].style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
        }
    }
        if (err){
        return false;
        }
    console.log(arr[1] + "test")
}
```

```css
.redPlaceholder::placeholder {
    color: red;
    font-style: italic;
    font-family: 'Roboto' sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<form name="form" method="post" netlify id="form"  onsubmit="return validate()" >
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name"><br>
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail"><br>
<input type="number" name="mobNumber" placeholder="Contact Number"><br>
<textarea name="query" placeholder="Your Query" rows="5"></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Edit: Instead of making a variable, can simply add `event` to the function when it is called. `onsubmit="return validate(event)"` and use `e` to represnt that when the function actually runs `function validate(e)` and if the for loop detects that one of the values is equal to zero, you can use the function `e.preventDefault()` to stop the form from submitting. Example here: https://jsfiddle.net/nukeboy212/vskt8epj/2/.

Comment: Also if you have any control of the backend here, it would be a good idea to make sure that these inputs are actually filled out as someone can just inspect element and delete the javascript.

Answer (score 1):

I would utilize `preventDefault` which will stop the form from submitting, allowing you to run what you need to and then telling the form to submit when you are actually ready.

Taken from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3350351/779600).

```
function validate(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  // Form stuff here
}
```

And update your form submit to:

```
<form name="form" method="post" netlify id="form" onsubmit="return validate(event)" >
```

Comment: Another answer I believe is to use `e.preventDefault()` in the for loop if one of the values equalts to "". Ill update my answer to do that.

Comment: @SirSpeciam Sure, ultimately placement doesn't really matter. But I feel most will put it at the very beginning of a function as a common practice. Found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4476994/779600

Comment: In this case it does because the person here wants the form to submit normally if the inputs are filled in correctly and if you were to place `preventDefault()` in the begining you would have to resubmit right after with another function when instead you could just use `preventDefault()` only when there is something wrong. "The simplest solution is just to not call e.preventDefault() unless validation actually fails." - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22363838/submit-form-after-calling-e-preventdefault/22363966